# Mouseover text from favorites bar lingers?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, microsoft-edge, favorites

For some reason, the mouseover text from one of my favorites in MS Edge is just staying on my screen, and I have no idea why.

[image: lingering title-text]

It even stays on my desktop when I minimize edge.

[image: title-text on the desktop]

Why is this happening?

Also, I don't know if this is related, but my taskbar icons act as if  I'm always mousing over one of them, and when my cursor is not hovering on the taskbar, whichever taskbar icon I moused over last stays highlighted and shows its name:

[image: taskbar mouseover error]

EDIT: The taskbar title-text disappeared when I switched virtual desktops, but the taskbar highlight stayed. FYI, this setting:

[image: settings]

Comment: I get this with Chrome sometimes, a mouseover text from a single window lingering on all my virtual desktops, until I track down the originating window and it disappears. I assume the cause might be similar, so curious to see if there's a solution.